# Фильтрация: пароль пользователя, данные из сессии

Tags: фильтрация, php

Хотел уточнить два момента по фильтрации.

1) Фильтровать принятый ПАРОЛЬ пользователя? 
   (Просто, мы его все равно хешируем, есть ли уязвимость, если не фильтровать)

2) Фильтровать данные из сессии?
   (Как по мне бред, но я спрошу, а то паранойя уже )

Comment: Нет фильтровать не нужно. Нужно экранировать.

Comment: что экранировать пароль и\или сессии?
И почему?

И зачем экранировать исходный пароль(если пароль) если он не выводиться на экран?

Comment: Экранировать данные, поступающие в запрос в виде переменных. Мало ли где какой спецсимвол проскочит.
А вообще давно пора переходить на `PDO` - при правильном использовании об sql-инъекциях можно думать меньше.

Comment: Обычные данные, типа логина, я экранирую.
А вот пароль нужно ли? если я его хеширую?

И к сессиям вообще это относится?

Comment: Как вариант:

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `a` = '" . $_SESSION["a"] . "'";
    $_SESSION["a"] = "'";

Да и с хэшами не всегда все гладко - алгоритмов много.

Comment: нужно не фильтровать и не экранировать а использовать bind

Comment: я и использую bind.
Но это не освобождает меня от моей паранойи))

Вот с сессиями. При присваивании данных из сессии переменой - с ней что нужно сделать?

Comment: так надо биндить параметры, а не составлять запрос типа 

    WHERE `a` = '" . $_SESSION["a"] . "'";

тут должно быть что-то вроде 

    WHERE `a` = ?

тогда никакой паранои, данные приходят в базу не через запрос а напрямую, это касается всех операций с базой, т.к. есть и sql injection 2го рода, скажем юзернэйм вы в сессию положили, а потом из нее делаете запрос, а он что нить типа `";blablabla`

Comment: Но, а что на счет вывода в браузер?
как фильтровать? использовать srip_tags и htmlspecialchars?